# In mainstream Sunni Islam, when was the last time a slave was legally recognized?

Tags: sunni, history, slavery

In [a fatwa](http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-1705/info) by Dr. Hatem al-Haj of the Assembly of Muslim Jurists of America, we see:

> Islam restricted the tributaries of slavery and widened the out channels, which ultimately depleted the entire river of slavery.

The idea is that: (a) through various means, Islam slowly eliminated slavery, and (b) in the interim, slaves were still recognized, but were to be treated well.  [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84431) enumerates some of these means, and says "Islam is the freer of slaves".

[A Dar Al-Ifta fatwa](http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=6830) gives a similar description, and writes:

> Slavery ended worldwide after the international treaty for the abolishment of slavery was signed in Berlin in 1860 AD. This has become a binding system that disallows anyone to enslave another. ... Based on the above, slavery is impermissible in the Shari'ah.

I want to get an approximation for when slavery was considered abolished.  Hence...

**Question**: In mainstream Sunni Islam, when was the last time a slave was legally recognized?

I choose to stick to Sunni Islam for this question, since it's possible other denominations recognized a slave, but that is disputed/unrecognized in Sunni Islam.  I also want to stick to mainstream views because there's always going to be rogue scholars.

One possible example are the [mamluks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamluk), but these are a bit different to an ordinary slave.

Comment: The [Barbary Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_Wars) were fought to stop Morocco from capturing Non-Muslims as slaves, so at least until 1815 there were Muslim countries actively engaged in piracy to enslave people ([expressly justified on Islamic grounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Barbary_War#cite_ref-25)). The [Arab slave trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_slave_trade) seems to have persisted into the 20th century.

Comment: @G.Bach . A lot of people try to defend their actions using Islam. That does not mean Islam (and mainstream scholars) allows their actions.

Comment: @TheZ Apologist rhetoric isn't useful here, the fiqh is pretty clear on that this was justified.

Comment: The statement of dar al-Ifta' seems hardly to go along with reality, Wikipedia says that slavery has been declared as unlawful in Mauritania only a decade ago! I guess your question is hard to answer as slavery could still be practiced "in secret". I myself knew a freed slave of some relatives who died a few years ago, so slavery surely still was practiced in the last century.